# How can I hide a div using visible property even it has a background

Tags: asp.net, html, visible

I have the following div:

```
<div visible="false" 
     style="background-image:url('../Contents/Images/item-background-selected.png'); width:113px; height:58px; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute;"  />
<div>
```

It's still visible in spite of the `visible` property is set to `false`. but when I remove the `background-image` from the style it's hidden.

How can I hide it with keeping its background?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 visible="false"
```

is a server control property, unless the div has

```
 runat="server"
```

set, it will be ignored, since the browser/client does not know how to handle that.

try CSS instead:

```
.myDivClass {

  display:none; /** or: visibility:hidden;  which is slightly different **/

  background-image:url('../Contents/Images/item-background-selected.png');
  width:113px; 
  height:58px; 
  background-repeat: 
  no-repeat; 
  position: absolute
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a go:

```
<div 
     style="background-image:url('../Contents/Images/item-background-selected.png'); width:113px; height:58px; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; display:none"  />
<div>
```

note the 'display:none'

To make it visible again you would have to remove the display:none from the div.

Comment: I think I can't, because I wanna bound the visible property with server side property and I think I can't do that with the style, right?

Comment: ok, let me know how it goes, as the Panel is actually a user control it will be easier to bind a property on it rather than using an HTML div

Comment: Thanks, I had to add `runat="server"` because I want to bind it. it works well now. +1 for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get to this in jQuery, use `show` and `hide`:

https://api.jquery.com/hide/

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('report').hide(); // no milliseconds provided means it hides immediately
});

function databound(e) {
    var data = e.sender.dataSource;
    if (0 < data.total()) {
        $('report').show(2000); // 2 seconds to open fully
    }
}
```

Just learning as I go, and sharing what I find.